# c# WPF SizeChanged event fires before main window is loaded

Tags: c#, wpf

I´m a newbie in WPF

I want to detect when main window size changes (with mouse grip), but event is fired before main window is loaded at start of the application. How come it is so?

```
    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Window is Resized");
    }
```

Comment: Your "before loaded" assumption is unlikely to be accurate.  It will happen when the native window is created, WM_SIZE is received very early.  Show the debugger's Call Stack window content.  And do consider that you'll have to write your code to deal with this.

Comment: Add the handler in the ContentRendered event.  Last event on show.  Should work fine.

Comment: I have no "ContentRendered" or "Loaded" in my XAML, that i guess have something to do with it?

Comment: How do i add SizeChanged handler to ContentRendered event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In first fire your previous size is 0,0 If you want to ignore it

You can try this:

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PreviousSize != new Size())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Window is Resized");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank´s Hadi
It works perfectly, but the event is firing twice?

Comment: In this case it doesn´t matter, because i´m closing the main window when trying to resize it.

Comment: Your' welcome  Mattias, actually no! zero size firing just before first rising of SizeChanged event one time.

Answer (score 1):

The window is initially 0 x 0. So on initial sizing, you get a notification depending on when you subscribed to the event. Do you only want to know when the window size has changed by the mouse resize? What about min / max, etc?

Comment: Yes, i want to have the window fully loaded, and then the event will fire when try to resize the main window by mouse.

Comment: No need for min,max, etc.. Just detect when size changes.

Comment: May i set the initial size somewhere?

Comment: @MattiasSturebrand, with WPF, you should *never* hard code window or control sizes or positions. Use the proper layout panels (Grid, StackPanel, etc.) and your window will scale the layout properly as it resizes. Are you trying to adjust controls when the window resizes or something? You shouldn't. Layout panels will do it for you.